# Error while using Geokit-Rails in model instance method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geokit

I am trying to use geokit-rails' .within helper method in a model instance method. Take a look here:

```
def self.crunch
        users = User.all

        users.each do |user|
            last_movement = Movement.where(user_id: user.id).try(:last)

            if last_movement
                users_near = Movement.where("user_id != ?", user.id).within(5, :origin => last_movement.user_lat, last_movement.user_lng)
            else
                next
            end

            if users_near.first
                users_near.each do |near|
                    #Make sure they don't exist in MB table

                    #Check for interests
                end
            end
        end
    end
```

I keep getting the error when I try to run the method: "SyntaxError: /Users/arsood/Documents/Consulting/SweetGlue_Service/app/models/matchbox.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected ')'"

Line 10 is:

```
users_near = Movement.where("user_id != ?", user.id).within(5, :origin => last_movement.user_lat, last_movement.user_lng)
```

When I remove the line it works fine. Is there a different way I need to call Geokit methods inside of a model rather than a controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the point is that origin needs a point or an array of lat and lng, you're passing 2 arguments so the synatx is wrong

This should work without problems

```
users_near = Movement.where("user_id != ?", user.id).within(5, :origin => [last_movement.user_lat, last_movement.user_lng])
```

Allow me to add a few notes on your code

- `where` always returns an active record relation, and running `last` on that would return nil if there's no records, no need to use `try`

  ```
  Movement.where(user_id: user.id).last
  ```
- if you are using rails 4, there's a nice `not` method for active record, 
  so you can change your query to something like this

  ```
  Movement.where.not(user_id: user.id).within(5, origin: [last_movement.user_lat, last_movement.user_lng])
  ```
- if you add an instance method that returns a point array that would be helpful

  ```
  class Movement < ActiveRecord::Base
     def point
       [ user_lat, user_lng ] 
     end
  end
  ```

  The query would be simpler

  ```
  users_near = Movement.where.not(user_id:user.id).within(5, origin: last_movement.point)
  ```
- I'm not sure what the users loop does, but i think it could be improved, if you explain what it's intended to do i could help with that too.

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you SO much. I really appreciate the time you spent making this a very complete and thorough answer.